# Calculate face rotation in Python (OpenCV)

Tags: python, geometry, trigonometry

I'm starting in **OpenCV** in **Python**. I made a code that can detect your face, eyes and smile. I need to get the rotation based on the position of eyes/points.

Example:

[image]

Is there any way of doing this with Python?

Comment: Just use the proper cyclometric function from `numpy` (`arccos` for example). You do know how to calculate the length of that line and differences along X/Y axis?

Answer (score 1):

If you have X and Y of 2 points you can use atan2 function. You can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Your code to calculate the angle between the points will go like this:

```
deltaY = point1_y - point2_y 
deltaX = point1_x - point2_x
my_radians = math.atan2(deltaY , deltaX)
```

If you want to convert radians to degrees

```
my_degrees = math.degrees(my_radians)
```

To convert from degrees to radians

```
my_radians = math.radians(my_degrees)
```